# How to use other shapes rather than rectangle, circle and svg in CustomShapeImageView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, svg

I am using CustomShapeImageView library. Find [HERE](https://github.com/MostafaGazar/CustomShapeImageView). I am unable to use other shapes like HEART. There are only three(3) options for app:shap attribute. They are Circle, Rectangle and SVG. See below...

[image]

How to use other shapes. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this library can be used to make any image. you can use heart shape svg image to make heart shape. You can check there are few sample images shown in example with library these all are svg images in raw folder in resource directory.

Comment: How can I see attribute options like heart in XML suggestions. I have googled it very hard but could not find it. Unfortunately this library has not good doc that describes how to use it properly. If you can help, It is very appreciable. Thanks in advance.@Akash Jain

Comment: try using below code to get heart shape imageview:

        <com.meg7.widget.SvgImageView
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:src="@drawable/sample"
        app:svg_raw_resource="@raw/shape_heart"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

for above code to work you should keep heart shape svg image in your raw directory in your project resources.

Comment: <com.meg7.widget.SvgImageView
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:src="@drawable/sample"
        app:svg_raw_resource="@raw/shape_heart"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

Comment: for above code to work you should keep heart shape svg image in your raw directory in your project resources.

Answer (score 1):

I quickly took a look to the library. You will have to update `attrs.xml` to add the shape you need and `CustomShapeImageView` to add support for the new value you declared in `attrs.xml`. E.g.

```
  <attr name="shape" format="integer">
        <enum name="circle" value="1" />
        <enum name="rectangle" value="2" />
        <enum name="svg" value="3" />
        <enum name="heart" value="4" />
  </attr>
```

Comment: Still not getting option of heart while pressing ctrl + space. I have also removed the library and added again.@Blackbelt

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help.@Blackbelt